# Почему не работает space-between (justify-content)?

Tags: css, flexbox

### CSS

Есть блок `body`.
У `body` есть два items: `header` и `footer`.
В `header` есть два ребёнка.
А у `footer` три ребёнка.
И есть общий контейнер `max-width: 1165px; height: 828px;`

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
}

footer {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Когда `footer__item` (три элемента внутри) я ограничиваю по ширине `max-widht: 280px;`
Общий контейнер становиться меньшим (>1165px).
И в `header` перестает работать свойство `justify-content: space-between;`
То есть два элемента прилегают друг к другу.
Когда убираю `max-width: 280px;` то три элемента заполняются свободное пространство (flex).

Нужно ограничить элементы в `footer` по ширине.

P.S. Если что могу дописать дополнительную информацию, или отправить полный HTML, CSS код.

для ответа на один из комментарий (TaniaLinn)
[image: скин]

Comment: добавьте в вопрос весь код, который воспроизводит проблему.

Comment: надеюсь вам подойдет ссылка на репозиторий
https://github.com/M0nday0001/supabase

Comment: "Нужно ограничить элементы в подвале по ширине" - кто такой этот ваш подвал?

Comment: @Andrew не подойдёт, минимальная **воспроизводимая** проблема должна быть **прямо в вопросе**. Подробнее о том как создать [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) в справке.

Comment: когда я добавляю вашему `.rectangle__card` свойство `max-width: 280px` нигде `justify-content: space-between` не перестает работать, шапка как была, такой и остается. Проблема не воспроизводится.

Comment: @NNL993 footer - извините за сленг.
нужно ограничить item в footer.

Comment: @TaniaLinn добавил скрин, там видно: с ограничения item footer - header и в общем body: уменьшился.

Comment: вижу скриншот. Так вас беспокоит не `space-between`, а то что родительский блок уменьшается по ширине? Это потому что вы задали ему только `max-width`, он знает только верхнее ограничение, а нижнего нет. Вот он и уменьшается до размеров своего содержимого. Задайте ему `min-width` и он меньше минимально указанной ширины уже не станет.

Comment: @ΝNL993 Если вам не подходит я не заставляю помочь мне, так же не тратьте свое время на меня. Спасибо, за ссылку на справочник, обязательно изучу. Это мой первый вопрос на Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TaniaLinn Ух ты ! все гораздо проще чем казалось )) спасибо, вам большое )

Answer (score 0):

Так вас беспокоит не space-between, а то что родительский блок уменьшается по ширине? Это потому что вы задали ему только max-width, он знает только верхнее ограничение, а нижнего нет. Вот он и уменьшается до размеров своего содержимого. Задайте ему min-width и он меньше минимально указанной ширины уже не станет. –
TaniaLinn
27 авг в 15:31

Спасибо еще раз за ответ